# How to enhance the mask part on the original image

Tags: python, image, opencv, contour

Original Image:

[image]

Masked Detected:

[image]

How can I only enhance the parts in white from the mask but on the original image?

```
enhance= cv2.convertScaleAbs(image, alpha=1.5, beta=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given

```py
mask = ...
enhanced = ...
```

you can do either

```py
# copy those pixels from source back over that aren't in the mask
enhanced[mask == 0] = image[mask == 0]
```

or

```py
# overwrite source with enhanced pixels, if they are in the mask
image[mask > 0] = enhanced[mask > 0]
```

this is numpy's indexing with boolean arrays (`mask == 0` results in a boolean array).